# Implementing express checkout (PayPal) using SOAP

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, paypal

So, here's my challenge: I have to build a webservice which handles payments using PayPal... The SOAP way! Since I'm a Node developer I'm very familiar with REST but the challenge is that I have to build it with Java, XML-schemas and SOAP using the Spring-framework. 
Now I found this workflow when using REST: https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/java?interactive=ON&env=sandbox.
That looks easy as pie to me! But what would this workflow look like when using SOAP and how would you implement this. As in: How do you handle redirects and responseURLs? Or is the workflow different?

P.S. I know PayPal has lots and lots of documentation but when it comes to SOAP, I just can't figure out the workflow or how to handle responseURLs..

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Take a look at Soap UI. It will allow you to construct raw requests and responses for talking to a SOAP based UI. Once you get a hang of the reqest and response information, take a look at this model https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you want to implement Express Checkout.

The flow is basically the same, different endpoints, but same steps. You can see the workflow here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleItemPayment-curl-etc/

Just reference the diagram. Everything below isn't specific to SOAP.

In brief, the flow looks like this:

```
1: Call SetExpressCheckout to get back a token.

2: Redirect to PayPal using token obtained in step 1.

3. If user accepts checkout then call GetExpressCheckoutDetails to get transaction details.

4. Use Token and PayerID (obtained in step 3) in call to DoExpressCheckoutPayment to capture payment.
```

Here's a good place to start: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/#ec

The first snag I ran into when implementing the SOAP API versus the REST API was that I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation where to find the redirect URL. The REST API will send it back, the SOAP does not. I had to dig through some of the SDK files to find it.

Redirect to here: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=